# Import and export data from gae datadtore in high replication

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to import and export data from gae app which configure with high replication datastore in java?

Ido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading/downloading data you can use [`bulkloader.py`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata).

If you need backup, there is now [backup functionality](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin) which allows you to backup datastore data to Blobstore or Google Cloud Storage.